# How can I get rid of the extra space at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, hide, mobile-website

I still new to coding and I was wondering if I am doing something wrong.
Is there a way I can get rid of all the extra space at the bottom under the text?
Here is the HTML.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
body {
    background-color: WHITE;
    width:100%;
    height:100vw;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.title {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    letter-spacing: 1.7px;
}

h1 {
    background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/26BROrSHlmyzzHf3i/giphy.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    color: transparent;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 120px;
    line-height: 1.01;
    margin: 40px 0;
    padding:0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: calc(3.35rem + 1vw);
  }
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 457px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: calc(2.5rem + 1vw);
    
    }
  
 
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
 <h1>Welome<br/>TO<br/>Website<br/>name</h1>
```

If you can help please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Or if anyone can help with the font sizing when the screen is smaller that would be great as well. Thanks

Comment: remove the height from the body

Comment: @TemaniAfif That helped with the desktop view but when it is mobile it is so small and not centered

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is what the mobile looks like https://imgur.com/a/Nc5qprC

Answer (score 1):

Your `h1` element has a `margin` value of 40px 0, which means it will have 40 pixels of top and bottom margin and 0 pixels of left and right margin. Here's [more info on writing short-hand margin properties](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_margin.asp). A proper `margin` value to remove the bottom margin would be 40px 0 0.

You also forgot to close your `div` tag:

```
<div class="title">
 <h1>Welome<br/>TO<br/>Website<br/>name</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks There still seems to be a problem. I still see the scroll bar and there is still extra space under the text

Comment: @amoney73 `body` has a style rule `height` of 100vw. I think you probably want 100vh instead, or no `height` rule at all. vw correlates to viewport width, vh correlates to viewport height

Comment: That helped with the desktop view but when it is mobile it is so small and not centered, sorry I keep asking questions

Comment: this is what the mobile looks like https://imgur.com/a/Nc5qprC

Answer (score 1):

As Alex Rummel pointed out, `height` should be corresponding with the viewport. Correcting this, say by changing it to `100%` or `100vh`, should rid you of the extra space and the scrollbar.

One way to do what you ask, regarding the cellphone view as well, is by using the flexbox in the parent container. So, if you insert the rule `display: flex` in your `div` tag, you can start manipulating the position of your `h1` tag.

*For you to be able to center everything*, horizontally and vertically, you should **explicitly** state the height (`height: 100vh`), and also include **the following three rules** in the parent container:

*`text-align: center`, in order to align the text inside the `h1` tag,*

*`justify-content: center`, in order to align the `h1` element horizontally, and*

*`align-items: center`, in order to align the `h1` element vertically*.

I hope this has been of help.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
body {
    background-color: WHITE;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.title {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #FFF;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    letter-spacing: 1.7px;
}

h1 {
    background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/26BROrSHlmyzzHf3i/giphy.gif);
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 120px;
    line-height: 1.01;
    padding:0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: calc(3.35rem + 1vw);
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 457px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: calc(2.5rem + 1vw); 
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./welcome.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <span><h1>Welome<br/>TO<br/>Website<br/>name</h1></span>
    </div>
</body>
```